# NSUserDefaults saving only one element in the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array that I am trying to access from multiple classes using `NSUserDefualts`. But when I `NSLog` the array, it will only save one at a time. For example I click on "A" and it saves and prints "A" but as soon as i click "B" it will forget "A" and only store "B". Here is my code. Let me know if you have any ideas.

FIRST CLASS

```
- (IBAction)pressedStarButton:(id)sender {
    if (starBarButton.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark_24.png"]) {
        starBarButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark_add_24.png"];
        [favPDFArray removeObject:cell_title_from_previous];
        NSMutableArray * tempArray = [favPDFArray mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"You removed Something");

        for (NSString * articleTitle in favPDFArray){
            if ([articleTitle isEqual:cell_title_from_previous])
                [tempArray removeObject: articleTitle];
        }

        favPDFArray = tempArray;
        for(NSArray *subArray in favPDFArray) {
            NSLog(@"Array in myArray: %@",subArray);
        }
    }
    else {
        starBarButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark_24.png"];
        NSLog(@"You Added Something");

        NSLog(@"%@",cell_title_from_previous);
        favPDFArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [favPDFArray addObject:cell_title_from_previous];
        for(NSArray *subArray in favPDFArray) {
            NSLog(@"Array in myArray: %@",subArray);
        }

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:favPDFArray forKey:@"favoritesArraySaved"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

SECOND CLASS

```
NSMutableArray *newFavoritesArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"favoritesArraySaved"];

for (NSString * articleTitle in newFavoritesArray){
    NSLog(articleTitle);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I think you should find a better way to identify the state of your buttons than checking their image, just a guess starBarButton.selected can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this:

```
favPDFArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It's creating a new array, that means that anything previously stored doesn't exist.  When you then set the NSUserDefaults "favoritesArraySaved" value to this array, it replaces the old one with this newly allocated one.

What it should be is this:

```
if (!favPDFArray) favPDFArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

This way, if 'favPDFArray' already exists, it doesn't rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense although after changing this line nothing has changed. The Array still only stores one value. Any ideas? Sorry but I'm stumped..

Comment: When you are initializing it and adding objects, to you first retrieve it from UserDefaults and add to this diictionary, or do you create a new dictionary, put an object in it, and overwrite this dictionary to user defaults?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on the functionality you are trying to achieve here but certainly you should not be using NSUserDefaults here. If you are trying to set a global object which could be set & get from multiple classes, try to utilize a singleton session class. And then to make sure the data is not getting wiped out you need to just insert or remove objects and no need to instantiate a new object every time.

A mutable array property on a singleton array would be a  better fit here.

But as mentioned by @guenis, please see if the functionality you are trying to achieve can be done in a simpler and straight forward way.